# Bash Script to kill linux processes not coming back to terminal

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I am new to Linux environment and working on writing scripts to start and stop few services(nodejs app bundled into executables using 'pkg' module). I want to stop processes by name and found 'killall' command. I tried this command individuaaly and inside bash script. Problem I am facing is, after executing kill command, control does not comeback to terminal and i need to use ctrl+c to get terminal back.

Here is script i tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run with command : chmod +x /root/myApp/stopserv.sh && /root/myApp/stopserv.sh

echo "Stopping Service1"
nohup killall  Service1 &>/dev/null &
echo "Stopping Service2"
nohup killall  Service2 &>/dev/null &
echo "Stopping Service3"
nohup killall  Service3 &>/dev/null &
echo "Stopping Service4"
nohup killall  Service4 &>/dev/null &
```

And when i run this script, I get response on terminal like below:

```
root@Phantom-E03E:~/myApp# chmod +x /root/myApp/stopserv.sh && /root/myApp/stopserv.sh
Stopping Service1
Stopping Service2
Stopping Service3
Stopping Service4
root@Phantom-E03E:~/myApp# /root/myApp/startserv.sh: line 17: 29535 Terminated    nohup ./Service1 &> /dev/null
/root/myApp/startserv.sh: line 11: 29533 Terminated              nohup ./Service2-linux &> /dev/null
/root/myApp/startserv.sh: line 14: 29534 Terminated              nohup ./Service3-linux &> /dev/null
/root/myApp/startserv.sh: line 8: 29527 Terminated              nohup ./Service4-linux &> /dev/null
```

I want to check:

1. Is there any other recommended way to stop executables in linux by name?
2. How to i get control back to terminal "root@Phantom-E03E:~/myApp#" after running script?

Thanks,
Pooja

Comment: It *is* finishing properly, the problem is that you’re running those `killall` commands in the background, and they’re producing output *after* the script has finished and exited. See that `root@Phantom-E03E:~/myApp# ` in the middle of the output? That’s the shell, prompting for your next command.

Comment: Correction: the late output isn’t coming directly from the `killall` commands themselves, but as a result of the processes being killed.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson. is there a way to get back to terminal control after printing messages. I am ok if messages are print. But with current behavior, it waits for user input to get terminal back.

Comment: You actually have control back, the display just looks weird. You could type in a command and it'd run normally, or you could just press return to get a new non-messed-up prompt. But really, you should figure out how to make the script wait until all messages have been printed (or suppress the messages), to prevent the display from looking weird.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson. This helps. I tried a hack to sleep for 2 secs after last line. This prints the terminated msg first and displays ctrl back to terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the script like:

```
<path_to_script> && exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it much better. Actually you can do it in two ways
 1. using foreground-background mechanism
 2. using systemd - service management ( a lit bit complicated )

### using fg / bg

When we run a process using shell (? bash) it will have interactively with our terminal. We can manage this interactivity by

- Control-Z (stop it, not quit, just pause)
- Control-C (stop it, kill
  == quit)
- fg ( bringing it back to foreground == interactivity )
- bg ( running it in background when it is stopped )

You can use this way manually or using a script. I will show both.
here is a screen-shot of doing manually

[image]

### using bash

here is a simple script

```
#!/bin/bash

APP_STATE=$1;
APP_NAME=$2;

# TASKS=( cont stop );

function stop_app(){
    APP_PID=$(pidof $APP_NAME);
    kill -n 19 $APP_PID;

    if [[ $? == '0' ]]; then
        echo "$APP_NAME paused!";
    else
        echo "could not pause $APP_NAME";
    fi
}

function continue_app(){
    APP_PID=$(pidof $APP_NAME);
    kill -n 18 $APP_PID;

    if [[ $? == '0' ]]; then
       echo "$APP_NAME continued ...";
    else
        echo "could not continue $APP_NAME";
    fi
}

case $APP_STATE in
    cont )
        continue_app ;;
    stop )
        stop_app  ;;

esac
```

and screen-shot of running this script

[image]

[image]

Note **bg** and **fg** are interfaces and you can do it in lower level using `kill` command by sending **stop signal** and **continue signal** which my script does it this way.

```
>>> kill -l
 1) SIGHUP   2) SIGINT   3) SIGQUIT  4) SIGILL   5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT  7) SIGBUS   8) SIGFPE   9) SIGKILL 10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV 12) SIGUSR2 13) SIGPIPE 14) SIGALRM 15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD 18) SIGCONT 19) SIGSTOP 20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN 22) SIGTTOU 23) SIGURG  24) SIGXCPU 25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF 28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGIO   30) SIGPWR
31) SIGSYS  34) SIGRTMIN    35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3
38) SIGRTMIN+4  39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12 47) SIGRTMIN+13
48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14 51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12
53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10 55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7
58) SIGRTMAX-6  59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
63) SIGRTMAX-1  64) SIGRTMAX
```

please notice signals **18** and **19**.

[image]

For a simple killing a process by name use `pkill` command.
For a complex management please take look at `/etc/systemd/system` directory
And if you have a **Node.js** server up and running and its management use either of [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) or systemd